# Finding the roots of a polynomial with symbolic coefficients

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, polynomials

As part of an assignment, I had to derive the equations of motion for a car's suspension system. Essentially it is a spring mass damper problem. The values for the car mass, M1, wheel mass, M2, the spring constant, k1 & k2 and the damping constant, c have not been given. I have derived the equations of motion and derived a transfer function relating the road surface (input) to the resulting car body displacement (output). 
I must determine the poles of this transfer function, hence I need to find the roots of the characteristic equation (denominator). The problem is that I do not have any values for the aforementioned variables and I am trying to either factorise my 4th order polynomial in MATLAB symbolically or calculate the roots straight away. 
I cannot assume any values, and it must be solved symbolically, however I do not know if this is possible in MATLAB.

I do not have a lot of experience with MATLAB so I am not aware of all its capabilities.

The characteristic equation I am trying to solve is :

`(M1*M2)*s^4 + c*(M1+M2)*s^3 + ((M1*k1)+(M1*k2)+c^2+(M2*k2)-c)*s^2 + k1*c*s + ((k1*k2)-(k2^2))`

Thank You in advance.

Comment: I may be able to help you, but I think the equation is not well described. You first need to write down well the equation. And then we will see the method to apply.

Comment: I have now corrected my errors in the equation, it should be correct now.

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors in your equation;

```
 c(M1+M2)*s^3 -> c*(M1+M2)*s^3
 + +k1*c*s -> + k1*c*s
```

But if you want to solve multivariate equations you can do it like this;

```
syms M1 M2 c k1 k2 s
eqn = (your equation) == 0;
roots = solve(eqn, s);
```

More information here: [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/solve.html)

Comment: Have you tried running this code? The returned "solution" is particularly helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Now you only need to follow this steps in case you only want to calculate the roots of the equation , which are similar to the previous comment:

```
1. syms c s
2. roots=solve((M1*M2)*s^4 + c*(M1+M2)*s^3 + ((M1*k1)+(M1*k2)+c^2+(M2*k2)-c)*s^2 + k1*c*s + ((k1*k2)-(k2^2)),s)
or
roots=solve((M1*M2)*s^4 + c*(M1+M2)*s^3 + ((M1*k1)+(M1*k2)+c^2+(M2*k2)-c)*s^2 + k1*c*s +((k1*k2)-(k2^2)),c)
or 
roots=solve((M1*M2)*s^4 + c*(M1+M2)*s^3 + ((M1*k1)+(M1*k2)+c^2+(M2*k2)-c)*s^2 + k1*c*s + ((k1*k2)-(k2^2)),s,c)
```

depending on the solution you want

Comment: The roots of the characteristic equation are in terms of `s`, which is what the OP is after, so your first equation is all that is needed. You should declare your other symbolic variable. Then, if you run this you'll see that it doesn't provide a useful solution by itself.

Comment: If you get your zeros and poles depending on the value of c, you can actually move them. Which I think he needs, thats why he doesnt have the value of it. In the other hand, the other way to calculate it is to put the equation in the way: G=A*s+B*s^2+C*s^3+D*s^4. Then G=minreal(tf(G));[R,p]=residue(G.num{1},G.den{1}); As you have no denominator its should answer 1.